# Print number of orders each products_id

Tags: php, sql, count

Is there a faster solution than mine?

I have a table with columns orders_id and products_id (can't change that)

Now I like to know how many orders made with unique products_id.

I tried the following. But it crashes while loading tooo many rows (160'000).

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT `products_id` ,  `products_name` , COUNT(*) as totalorders FROM  `orders_products` ORDER BY  `products_id` ASC
```

I tried also with subqueries, but same problem as above.

```
    SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM orders_products WHERE products_id = op.products_id) AS totalorders, products_id, products_name FROM orders_products op ORDER BY products_id ASC
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `GROUP BY`? If this is MySQL, post the `EXPLAIN` output.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT `products_id`, `products_name`, COUNT(*) FROM `orders_products` GROUP BY (`products_id`, `products_name`) ORDER BY `products_id`
```

Comment: Since you are aggregating on the products_id, you need an aggregate function on products_name OR you need to include it in the grouping.

Comment: @TDrudge nice spot. Corrected the answer. Thank ya.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have an index on products_id

In that case, I would try something like the following:

select products_id, Min(Products_Name), count(*) as TotalOrders
from Orders_Products
Group by Products_ID
Order by Products_ID asc

There are a couple of other ways that you could grab the products_name, such as including it in your grouping (some other implications there).